# is_module guard clause in elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm passing module to the function and want to use guard clauses (function is designed to have :atom or module) passed to it.

How can I check that argument in the function is module (like `is_atom` for atoms?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with just guard clauses. I would use [`Code.ensure_loaded?/1`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Code.html#ensure_loaded?/1) in the function body for this. In addition to returning true/false if the module exists or not, this will also try to load the module if it can find the corresponding beam file in the code path:

```
iex(1)> defmodule A do
...(1)> end
iex(2)> Code.ensure_loaded?(A)
true
iex(3)> Code.ensure_loaded?(B)
false
iex(4)> Code.ensure_loaded?(Map)
true
iex(5)> Code.ensure_loaded?(:maps)
true
# I created `a.beam` using `erlc` in the same folder as `iex` was started
iex(6)> Code.ensure_loaded?(:a) 
true
```

Comment: Hm, how can I use this as guard clause in my function?

Comment: Please see my edit. That is not possible in guard clauses. `is_atom` is the only check you can do in the guard that will eliminate things that can't possibly be modules, but it can't check if a module exists.

Comment: Hm, I don't want to check for the module existing, I want to check that module is passed instead of atom

Comment: A module is just an atom. `Foo` is syntactic sugar for `:"Elixir.Foo"` in Elixir.

Answer (score 1):

A module name IS an atom, so other than checking for is_atom, what you're requesting is impossible.